# How to add comments without authentification required

Tags: python, django, web, comments

i just done comments on my website,and i want to do non-authorized comments,and dont know how to.My models looks like this

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete = models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Page', blank = True, null = True,related_name='comments' )
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete = models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Comment author', blank = True, null = True )
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name='Comment text', max_length=500)
    status = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Visible', default=False)
```

and views.py like this

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.article = self.get_object()
        self.object.author = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.get_form()
    if form.is_valid():
        return self.form_valid(form)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)

def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    self.object.article = self.get_object()
    if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
        self.object.author = self.request.user
    else:
       self.object.author = None
    self.object.save()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

note: remove else block if you get an error

Comment: from where i need to get 'user'?